# What to infer from t.test paired = FALSE from father.son dataset in R?

Tags: r, statistics, dataset, confidence-interval

I was trying to understand father.son data set with t.test confidence interval.

When we do paired = TRUE, output = 0.83 1.16

when we do paired = FALSE,output = 0.76 1.23

What I infer from this is that, when we have paired =TRUE , it means overall sons are higher than their paired fathers (when 2 populations are compared, and which are also linked), but I dont get what to infer when paired = FALSE?

PS: I don't have a statistics background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `paired=TRUE` if you were testing the same set of subjects using different conditions to compare if there is a difference in observations due to the new conditions.

So, if 200 elderly men were measured for flexibility as a base line with a series of measurements taken, then they were treated with a therapy or exercise regimen for a few weeks and observed again, you would use a `paired=TRUE` T-test to ascertain if the difference is significant within the SAME TEST GROUP under DIFFERENT CONDITIONS.

Because you are comparing ONE SAMPLE to DIFFERENT SAMPLE based on height, you are *not* looking at a paired situation.

They are completely separate test subjects (despite the relationship). So, you would use paired=FALSE in this situation to see if the difference between TWO sample groups is statistically equivalent. You use `summary(ttest)` to evaluate the results (substituting the variable name against which you set the `t.test`).

Comment: Thank you Bethany.

Comment: Doubt. If when we do paired = TRUE it (=t.test) gets the difference between x[i] and corresponding y[i], and gets the 95% confidence interval of the differences, so what sort of calculations does it do when paired = FALSE, because I can't think if it doesn't do x[i] - y[i], then what does it do?

Comment: It is not as simple as that.. you might want to read up. Here is a solid resource on the t.test and R-  https://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/independent-t.html    Here is one on the upaired with formulas http://www.statsdirect.com/help/parametric_methods/utt.htm  and one on paired  http://www.statsdirect.com/help/parametric_methods/ptt.htm also with formulas. See how they are calculated differently and the reasoning behind it.